# Display numbers from 0 to X vis versa

Tags: java

i need your help in this puzzle:
i want to take an input from the user as X and display numbers from 0 to X and from X to 0.
the trick is to use only one variable.
how could i solve this in java

Comment: Use recursion...

Comment: Do you have to use the `String[]` passed to the main method to do everything then?

Answer (score -2):

You can use `IntStream` if you are on Java 8 or later.

```
int x = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
IntStream.rangeClosed(0, x).forEach(System.out::print);
System.out.println();
IntStream.rangeClosed(0, x).boxed().sorted(Collections.reverseOrder()).forEach(System.out::print);
```

Comment: `int x = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();`?  They wanted input from the user.  (Someone else downvoted, I didn't downvote for this point.)

Comment: @BeUndead that I understood  I assumed that OP new how to get user input.

Comment: Downvoter could let me know what i did wrong.